# Laravel - eloquent relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is meal table:

Id,
Category_Id

This is categories table:

Id,
Slug

How do I define relationship between those 2 (return array Meal with array category inside to get slug)
I tried putting this:

meal.php

```
function returnCategories()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

and this doesnt work

Edit:

In Controller file I want to define it like:
`Meal::with('returnCategories');`

Controller code:
`return Meal::select('id')->with('category')->get();`

Comment: please share the controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function returnCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'Category_Id', 'Id');
}
```

or you can try

```
function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'Category_Id', 'Id');
    }
```

and try using select(*). this worked for me.

```
    $meals = Meal::select( '*' )->with('category')->get();
```

Comment: this returns me null

Comment: does every meal has one category?

Comment: Yes, that is the case every meal can have only one category

Comment: Comment on your edit, I tried that and it's not working too :( null value

Comment: is it 'category_id' or 'Category_Id'? are you using upper case in Database?

Comment: Yes, I am using in base Category_Id too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229524/discussion-between-r89human-and-nniks19).

Comment: try using   $meals = Meal::select( '*' )->with('category')->get();

Comment: Can you update answer to that so I can upvote